# Android debug database can't reach site

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to use the https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database library.

According to the instructions I added to the build.gradle the implementation line `com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6`.
Using the default emulator, I start debugging, logcat correctly displayed the message "DebugDB: Open http://10.0.2.16:8080 in your browser".
In the console I entered `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080` attempt to enter the browser on a laptop on url http://localhost:8080 ends with "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE", even the attempt to enter the url http://10.0.2.16:8080 in the emulator browser looks the same.

What could be the problem? I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: hi, have u found the solution? I am having the same issue.

Comment: hi, it worked for me I was using the wrong forward command `adb forward tcp:8080 8080` instead of `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080` you also might have some similar mistake

Comment: Hi, I used Android studio database inspector and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my case. Just change the port as described in git [repo][1]:

> Note : If you want use different port other than 8080. In the app
> build.gradle file under buildTypes do the following change
>
> `debug {`
>    `resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8081")`
> `}`

It worked for me.
[1]: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database