# Cannot connect to Android Debug Database, even changing port

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, android-debug

I am trying to use [Android Debug Database](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database) to see the contents of my local Room DB. The phone is correctly connected to USB Debug and I can see the logs on logcat in Android Studio. However, if I try to connect to the address that it gives me, the browser seems unable to connect (I tried both Chrome and Firefox). I even changed the default port to other values [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64321118/15209990), but I still have no success.

All I did, aside from changing the port, was to add `debugImplementation 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.6'` to my `build.gradle`.

What could I be doing wrong? I am developing the app in Kotlin if it helps.

Comment: While this might not answer your question, you might want to consider using the built in Database Inspector instead.  More information is at https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/database.

Comment: Maybe the problem is not the port, are you using a static ip in your internet connection? I had that problem, in my case I just let my adapter get automatically the ip and it solved the problem, even the ip given by the library was different. I don't know if that's your case